# UVM/SV: syntax error on class declaration

Tags: reference, package, system-verilog, hierarchical, uvm

I am facing following issue in one of my code.

> Error-[SE] Syntax error Following verilog source has syntax error :
> token 'monitor' should be a valid type. Please declare it virtual if
> it is an Interface. monitor m_monitor;

I have file named `monitor.sv` where I am using class monitor . I have declared that class in another file named `soc_uvm.svh`.

from `monitor.sv`

```
class monitor 
//body contains lots of hierarical paths  
endclass
```

From `soc_uvm.svh`

```
class soc_uvm_env extends uvm_env  
//DEclare  
monitor m_monitor ;  
endclass
```

from `pkg.sv` file

```
Package soc_uvm_pkg  
`include soc_uvm.svh  
endpackage
```

This soc_env.svh is again include in pkg.sv file.

Comment: This looks very similar to another question I have seen recently. You have not given enough information to enable anyone to help you. When the compiler tries to compile `soc_uvm.svh` it has not yet compiled the code that declares the class `monitor`; it is not being compiled at all or is being compiled in the wrong order.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that the `monitor` class is missing from the scope of the `soc_uvm_env` in other words during compilation of soc_uvm.svh compiler cannot resove `monitor` as it doesn't know that type.

I expect that you have something following:

```
//monitor.sv
class monitor extends xy;
  //Some stuff
endclass : monitor
```

```
//soc_uvm.svh
class soc_uvm_env extends uvm_env;
  //Declaration
  monitor m_monitor;
  //Some other stuff 
endclass : soc_uvm_env
```

```
//pkg.sv
package soc_uvm_package;
  ...
  `include "monitor.sv" // <- Isn't this missing?
  `include "soc_uvm.svh"
  ...
endpackage
```

If you haven't included the file "monitor.sv" into the same package you probably need to **import** the package where monitor.sv is included `import pkg_where_mon_is::*;` or `import pkg_where_mon_is::monitor;`. Or **include** the "monitor.sv" into your package.
So following could fix it.

```
package soc_uvm_package;
  ...
  import pkg_where_mon_is::*; //Will import whole package
  //or
  import pkg_where_mon_is::monitor; //should import only class monitor from package
  `include "soc_uvm.svh"
  ...
endpackage
```

---

Just a side advice I would look into some styleguide for naming conventions like on this link [here](https://www.systemverilog.io/styleguide).